# Image to particle transition onscroll

Tags: javascript, html, particles

I came across this website and want to replicate the effect on the front page. The image will transition into particles on scroll effect

here's the link to the site: https://green-ribbon.com/

does anyone know what js script or how they are doing it?

Comment: There's a canvas element that is responsible for the animation. In viewing the javascript responsible for rendering the animation, it appears to be obfuscated. You could try to reverse engineer it and see how they're doing it. If you want my personal opinion, I'd just steer clear of it entirely as the page load time is tremendously slow and isn't worth the trade off if this is something you're going to implement for users visiting your website.

I'd just look at alternative open source animations.

Comment: I'm just curious on how they code that kind of effect from image then turns to pixelated version then explosion effect for every pixel color